# Filter Results before Django Renders form fields in a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am attempting to create a series of forms on a site that all use the same Region foreign key. Here is the Region Model:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region_name = short_varchar_r()
    member = models.BooleanField()
    organization = models.BooleanField()
    calendar = models.BooleanField()
    college = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.region_name
```

There are 4 forms on the site for selecting Region. Each needs to render a select field that has only the Regions specific to that form. IE: Member requires only Regions that have Member set to True.

Here is the member form:

```
class NewsletterRequest(models.Model):
    member_type = short_varchar_r(choices=MEMBER_TYPE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    region = models.ForeignKey('Region')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

And the College Field

```
class College(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey('CollegeType', null=True, blank=True)
    gender = short_varchar_o(choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
    ...
    region = models.ForeignKey(
                    'Region',
                    null=True,
                    blank=True,
                    related_name='region'
                )
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT: fixed the Region model to be (models.Model) rather than (Models.Model). Problem persists.

Comment: How are you storing which regions are available to each form?